# Update product sku with customs options skus on product pages and cart

Tags: custom-options, ajax, product-attribute, sku, simple-product

How can I dynamically update the sku of a product on the product page when users select its custom options?  Also, how could it then be passed into the cart page?

Example:  A product with sku XXX has two custom options Y and Z, which have the options of Y1, Y2 and Z1, Z2.  If a user selects Y1 and Z2, I'd like to change the sku on the page to XXX-Y1-Z2 and pass that sku to the cart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a custom options to a product you can add, for example for dropdown options, a product sku suffix as shown below.

[image]

On choosing an option when adding the product to cart and retrieving the SKU in the cart `var_dump($_item->getSku());` you can see the products SKU has been changed

[image]

Now for dynamically updating the SKU on the product page. For this we will need to retrieve the option values SKU's which can be done in the file `app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml` for example. In this case around line 190 after the javascript we add/replace some code as shown below. This will give you a javascript array which you can use when a custom option is selected to map the option ID to the SKU suffix and changing the displayed product SKU on the product page.

```
<dl>
    <?php $options_to_sku = array();?>

    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
<?php
if ($_option->getType() == 'drop_down')
{
    $options_to_sku["{$_option->getId()}"] = array();
    foreach ($_option->getValues() as $k => $v) 
    {
        $options_to_sku["{$_option->getId()}"]["{$v->getData('option_type_id')}"] = $v->getData('sku');
    }
}
?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var options_to_sku = <?php echo json_encode($options_to_sku);?>;

        $$('.product-custom-option').each(function(elm) {
            $(elm).observe('change', function() {
                var sku_suffix = '';
                $$('.product-custom-option').each(function(opt) {
                    if ($(opt).value.length==0) // no value selected
                        return;

                    var opt_id = $(opt).readAttribute('id').replace('select_','');

                    if (!!!options_to_sku[opt_id]) // no option values array found
                        return;

                    if (!!!options_to_sku[opt_id][$(opt).value]) // no sku found matching value id
                        return;

                    sku_suffix += '-' + options_to_sku[opt_id][$(opt).value]; // add to suffix
                });

                /**
                 * add here the code that adds the suffix to your SKU
                 */
                console.log(sku_suffix);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sander. This is close, but the array only includes the id and the sku of the last option for each custom option. So, it looks like: var options_to_sku = {"id1":"LastOptionSku1","id2":"LastOptionSku2"};

Also, I couldn't get js to use the array to ammend the sku. So, I used jQuery to update the options. See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmX7E/9/). But, this requires the id of the <select> element, which I couldn't get dynamically.  And, it appends the option's value to the product sku instead of the option's sku.  (oh, and it's jQuery, because I couldn't js or prototype to work).

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a multidimensional array. So now it should create an array with options for each dropdown. Adding the ID or any other HTML to the select takes a lot of rewriting. After work (in 8 hours) ill put this in a test shop and debug it for you reporting back with a full answer :)

Comment: @Dustin updated my code with PHP changes and working javascript (prototype). I've tested it on a clean Mage 1.8 install

Comment: you are brilliant. That works perfectly. Thanks for all the help.  In case you or future readers want my code to add the suffix, I put a container in the html, <div id="sku-container"></div>. At the top of the js, I added: $("sku-container").update("<strong>Configuration: <?php echo $this->getProduct()->getSku(); ?></strong>");  and in your js, I added $("sku-container").update("<strong>Configuration: <?php echo $this->getProduct()->getSku(); ?></strong>" + (sku_suffix)); Thanks again.

Comment: @SanderMangel I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and would like some help please.  My Magento version is 1.9.1 and I have pasted the code to my options.phtml page here: http://www.pastebin.com/QcsVyqct  Any help is appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Product page

Add the sku to the product page, add a few lines of JS, listen on `change` on the `<select>` and change the sku.

## Cart

Implement an observer, listen to `checkout_cart_product_add_after` take the product, check for the custom options and change the sku of the `quote_item`. The `quote_item` is saved afterwards, so no need to save it inside the controller.

```
$quoteItem->setSku();
```

Done.

Comment: Can you point me toward references or examples. I'm not sure I understand how this would update anything on the product page.

Comment: Damn. Didn't read the part with the product page. This wouldn't :D I would add a few lines of JS to achieve this. Sorry for missing